# active menu background for all the nodes of a particular content type

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a view to list the nodes of a particular content type.I have given a path and linked it to a menu item.I am changing the background of the menu item when it is active or visited.Also i want to change the menu background when the node in the view is viewed so that it should look like active menu.Thanks in advance.